A faster method for converting meters to degrees
I have this algorithm, written in C++, that converts meters to degrees using OGR and GDAL.
OGRSpatialReference source, target;
OGRCoordinateTransformation* transform;
const char* projection = geotiff->GetProjectionRef();
source.importFromWkt(projection);
target.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");

transform = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&source, &target);

for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
        if (transform->Transform(1, &coords[0][i][j], &coords[1][i][j], 0) == 0) {
            // error message here
        }
    }
}

return coords;

According to Visual Studio, around 60% of my run-time actually comes from the Transform and my code runs for almost a minute. Is there any way to decrease the runtime here?

Deprojection is a computationally expensive task. You haven't indicated how many iterations are involved.

For now, I am re-projecting around 49 million points.

First of all, you are not just converting "meters to degrees".
Anyway, OGR uses the PROJ library for the coordinate transformation: you can try to directly use the PROJ library.

You could also try to use the GeographicLib library.

You can set the n_count to the length of your arrays and pass the whole problem to the transform function. Then you save (at least) the overhead of thousands (millions?) of function calls. I would expect there to be some saving in terms of how much work the function does to set up the transform too.
See the manual page for more details of what the parameters should be.

I re-stored all of the points into two arrays and passed them onto transform. The function now takes around 50% of the processing time. Although, according to Vince, Transform is computationally expensive, I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Half a minute for 50 million deprojection calculations involving multiple trig function calls is pretty spry.
